# llamada php a python

Tags: php, python

Tengo una llamada desde php a python de la siguiente forma:

PHP

```
    $command = "python3 /var/www/html/py/setup.py '";
    $command .=$json;
    $command .="'";
    echo shell_exec($command);
```

El problema es que dentro de setup.py hago una llamada a otro script python que logea todas las peticiones y este es el misterio.
Si la llamada a setup.py la hago desde php, la llamada desde setup.py a logger.py no funciona, pero si lanzo la misma petición desde consola a setup.py, logger.py se ejecuta y logea sin problema.

setup.py

```
     subprocess.check_output("python3 /var/www/html/py/logger.py 'peticion: "+sys.argv[1]+"'", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Un tema de permisos en linux. el servidor ngix no tenia permisos para escribir en el archivo de log.  Nunca te acostaras sin saber una cosa mas.